# OAF - Compare current row with next row

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have a requirement where, there are two columns having 5 rows each.

i want a validation in OAF where, the 2nd row of the 2nd column is compared with 1st row of 1st column

say,  X , Y are two columns

### X     Y

1.1   -  2.1

1.2     2.2

1.3     2.3

1.4     2.4

1.5     2.5

My requirement is to compare   2.1 with 1.2 and display a message if 2.1 is greater or lesser than 1.2

Kindly respond.
Regards.

Comment: can you offer the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

greatest  can be made use to find the value greater between two values.

SCOTT@rnd 23-SEP-14> select id, field , greatest(id,field) "greater value" from id;

```
    ID      FIELD greater value
```

---

```
     1         10            10
     1         11            11
     1         12            12
     1         13            13
```